# Linux kernel contiuguous memory allocation for skbuff

Tags: linux, networking, memory, memory-management, kernel

When structures like the skbuff are allocated by the Linux kernel, is the data area allocated (skbuff->tail - skbuff->head) always a contiguous memory block, or can this be non-contiguous?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
Yes. The memory range [`skbuff->end - skbuff->head`] is always a contiguous memory block.

**Long Answer:**
Still yes, but if your skbuff is fragmented (later I will explain how to check if it's fragmented or not) then your data won't lie on one contiguous memory block. Please note that the data in the range of `[skbuff->end - skbuff->head]` is still in one contiguous memory block, but not all the data of the fragmented skbuff lies in the range of `[skbuff->end - skbuff->head]`.

If you want to get a deeper understanding of how to work with `fragmented skbuff`, then I recommend to read [this](http://amsekharkernel.blogspot.com/2014/08/what-is-skb-in-linux-kernel-what-are.html) (and start reading from this title **When SKB is Non Linear**). I think the explanations there are clear and also visualized.

**How can I tell my skbuff is fragmented ?**
In the case the that you are not the one that allocate the skbuff, and you want to understand if the data of the skbuff you are working with is fragmented or not, you can just check the value of `skb->data_len`:

- If it's equal to 0, then the skbuff is linear (not fragmented - the data lies on contiguous memory block) and the size of the data is `skb->len`.
- If it's greater then 0, the the skbuff in not linear (the data is fragmented), were `skb->len` is still the length of the
  full frame and `skb->data_len` is the total length of all the data fragments not
  counting the first fragment.

You can also just call `skb_is_nonlinear()`, and if it returns `true`, then the skbuff is fragmented (lies on physically-non-continuous memory).

**Bonus:**
If you received a fragmented skbuff and you cannot work with fragmented skbuffers (because your HW doesn't support it or some other reasons), then you can reshape this fragmented skbuff into a new skbuff linear skbuff (not fragmented) by using the funtion [skb_copy()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/skbuff.c#L1510). But keep in mind that this function will create a copy of the original skbuff, so this operation will cost you...
Hmmm.. And don't forget to release the original skbuff.